# Is it safe to store authentication token in HTML local storage?

Tags: iphone, android, rest, cordova

Im building Phonegap application that uses token authentication strategy to access rest services. Is it safe to use HTML 5 local storage to save access token there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if phonegap requires the application key to be passed along with the session token for them to be valid.  If the application key is safely stored inside your application code, then handing out the session tokens is safe.

But do note that HTML 5 local storage is accessible for anyone who has a rooted phone and goes through the app's files.

Your best bet is to do a basic key encryption on the session token if you want to play it safe.